# Como fazer um POST com "multipart/form-data" utilizando C# em aplicações Console?

Tags: c#, api, post, console

to tentando fazer assim e não tá funcionando:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlFinal);

var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "answer"
};

content.Add(fileContent);

var result = httpClient.PostAsync("file/upload", content).Result;

Console.WriteLine("Status: " + result.StatusCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma arrumada no seu código, veja como ficou:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("Upload"))
    {
        content.Add(fileContent);

        var result = client.PostAsync("file/upload", content).Result;

        using (var message = client.PostAsync("file/upload", content).Result)
        {
            var response = message.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

            Console.WriteLine("Status: " + result.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Algumas observações:

- está usando os métodos async de forma síncrona e esperando o
  `Result`, tente transformar seu método em async e usar `await` nas
  operações async (por exemplo `await client.PostAsync("file/upload",
  content)`.
- não vi no seu código, mas alguns objetos são *disposable*, ou seja, eles podem ser usando dentro de um bloco de código `using`, como o
  `HttpClient`, que irá liberar os recursos assim que o bloco using for encerrado. Se não sabe como funciona, pesquise aqui mesmo no site
  tem várias perguntas e respostas sobre o assunto.